# How to Tell What Line Something is on in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Basically, I have some static arrays in my code like the following:

```
private string[] mFirst = new string[10] { "Amy", "Scott", "Jamie", "Sharon", "Brock", "Baxtor", "John", "", "", "" };
```

So I have to store some data for users in the program. Now, in the program I display this stored data into a listBox. From there, the user can add more data to it and display it as well.

The problem is that I'm trying to allow a user to delete entries. I have the delete function working properly. The problem is it only removes it from the listbox and isn't actually removing it from stored inside the program. So when I redisplay the stored entries to the user, it reappears since it was never really deleted.

My question is how to decide which line the user deletes and which data entry that correlates to? I thought about assigning each array entry a number and then running a loop after that to remove that stored entry, but I wouldn't know where to begin to do that or if there is an easier way to do this that I just don't know of.

EDIT:

```
ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = lstOutput.SelectedItems;

List<object> fixedItems = new List<object>();
fixedItems.Add(mFirstLine);
fixedItems.Add(mAverage);
fixedItems.Add(mHigh);
fixedItems.Add(mLow);
fixedItems.Add(mSpace);

for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (fixedItems.Contains(selectedItems[i]) == false)
    {
        lstOutput.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
    }
}
```

This is what my delete method looks like. I know it isn't the best. All the fixedItems.Add are labels that I have that I don't want to be deleted.

To answer all the questions, I have to have a static array. It's not by choice; the assignment requires it. I completely agree dynamic is the way to go, but again, it has to be static. So @No Idea For Name, not sure if your suggestion will work with a static array.

This is Windows Forms.

@dav_i Not sure why i would delete everything and add it again. All I need to do is be able to delete that entry that they selected, which is stored, and then I would add everything after that. I can delete it from the listbox, but not sure how to delete it where it is actually stored in my program, since I need to know exactly which entry it is at in the array.

@AMR No idea what databind is. I'll look at it

Comment: are we talking about windows forms or wpf?

Comment: Why not delete everything and add it in again?

Comment: How are your deleting it from the lisbox , is It ListView1.Items.Remove(ListView1.SelectedItems(0)); ?

Comment: Instead of doing all this crazy adding and removing from the listbox why not just databind to it. Then you only have to deal with the list in code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984341(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You have a wrong desing. Try to separate data from the representation and user interaction. Always perform operation on the underlying data (Add, Delete, Move) and refresh representation afterwards (to example, with event, which is called after Add or Delete modify data, and your form is subscribed to this event to redraw the whole list at once).

Comment: How you remove item from the listbox? What's the code for that? Please reply to comments with comments, not inside the question body. Use `@` to notify each user you want to be notified.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. The code for how I am deleting the item from the listbox is in the edit.

Comment: @user2781018 so let me understand. You are removing from the listbox items that do not exist in the fixed array and you want to remove them from the fixed array too? but they don't exist there in the first place. :confused:

Comment: @No Idea For Name. I thought I had to use a static array, but I think a dynamic will still work. I'll try the suggestion. I'll have to do a lot of editing of the code, so it will take a bit.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard you confused me to. Not sure why you are saying I'm removing items that do not exist. So right now, if they add something to the array, it will appear in the listbox and the array. It is there for the duration of the program and will be gone upon closing the program. And the static entries aren't actually deleted by my delete method. They are just removed from the listbox, but is still actually in the array itself.

Comment: @user2781018 this line: `if (fixedItems.Contains(selectedItems[i]) == false)` means "if the current item does not exist in the fixedItems array". So you can't remove something that does not exist.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: well I changed that line to true. Then, I added all of the arrays, so it's like fixedItems.Add(mFirst);  but now it isn't even removed from the listbox. Before it was removed from the listbox, but not the array.

Comment: Sorry, I give up. Hope someone else will figure your logic, otherwise if you ever try a different logic edit your post and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you 2 things.

1. Use a generic List, which is more dynamic. You don't know how many items the user would like and it would be easier to remove from it:

   do

   ```
   List<string> mFirst = new List<string>();
   mFirst.AddRange(new string[] { "Amy", "Scott", "Jamie", "Sharon", "Brock", "Baxtor", "John", "", "", "" });
   listBox1.Items.AddRange(mFirst.ToArray());
   ```
2. to remove the item you can now do

   ```
   mFirst.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
   ```

And you can do it when you remove the item from the `listBox` (before your remove it from the `listBox`)

Comment: Note that if a user adds a second `Amy` and then wants to delete the second `Amy`, this code would remove the first `Amy` from the list instead.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis well, that's the problem with too simple types... gimmi a second i'll fix that